# XML not parsing correctly using requests and lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to get content out of XML from an API call.  I'm able to use requests to get the xml content, but can't seem to parse it correctly.  Here is the code that has been semi-successful so far:

```
    import requests
    from lxml import etree
    data = requests.get('http://elections.huffingtonpost.com/pollster/api/polls.xml', params={'sort':'updated'})
    tree = etree.XML(data.content)
```

The tree is showing the line breaks from the xml as text, and some of the nodes that are more than 3 levels deep are gone.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data? Line breaks are trivial to fix after extraction, if you need them and what do you mean by "some of the nodes that are more than 3 levels deep are gone"  ?

Comment: I want to get the results of certain polls. For example `tree[0][11][0][0]` should tell me the first question in the most recent survey

Comment: This is not how you parse XML, don't treat it like a list or dictionary. Use xpath to get what you need. [example](http://pastie.org/10745894)